# Intellij Messages tool window not available

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on gradle project in intellij 14 ...  however 'Messages' tool window is not available from View | Tool Windows so that I can't jump around among errors.  Why 'Messages' tool window is not available for me??

Thanks a lot!
sl

Answer (score 0):

The Messages toolwindow appears when you build a project (Build | Make Project), and shows the result of the build. If you never run the build, the toolwindow will not appear.